# Refactoring; How to make one class ignorant of another?

Tags: c#, refactoring

### A Quick Note

This issue does not rely on 3D based code, nor logic; it simply focuses on removing the dependency of one object from another, and I am trying to be as thorough as possible in describing the issue. While having some 3D background will probably help understand what the code is doing, it is not needed to separate class A from class B. I believe this task will be solved with some logical, yet lateral thinking.

---

### Overview

I'm refactoring some old code (written sometime in the early 90s) and there are a few classes that rely on other classes. This question will focus on a single class that relies on another single class (no other dependencies in this case). The project is a DirectX project that simply renders a few objects to the screen for working purposes. I can't really give a thorough description unfortunately; however, I can explain the problem with the code.

There are two classes that I need to focus heavily on, one of which I am currently re-writing to be generic and reusable since we now have a secondary need for rendering.

- Engine3D (Currently Re-Writing)
- Camera3D

I will explain in more detail below, but the gist of the situation is that `Engine3D` relies on `Camera3D` in the `Render` method.

---

### `Engine3D`'s Current Flow

The current flow of `Engine3D` is heavily focused on accomplishing a single goal; rendering what the project needs, and that's it.

```
public void Render() {
    // Clear render target.
    // Render camera.
    // Set constant buffers.
    // Render objects.
    // Present back buffer.
}
```

The update code and the render code are all jumbled together and every object that is rendered to the screen, is located in the `Render` method. This isn't good for reusability as it forces the exact same scene to be rendered each time; therefore I am breaking it down, creating a generic `Engine3D` and then I will utilize it in my (let's call it `Form1`) code.

---

### The New Flow

The idea is to make rendering objects to the screen a simple task by making a `Draw` call to the `Engine3D` and passing in the object to be rendered. Much like the old days of `XNA Framework`. A basic representation of the new flow of `Engine3D` is:

```
// I may move this to the constructor; if you believe this is a good idea, please let me know.
public new virtual void Initialize() {
    base.Initialize();
    OnInitialize(this, new EventArgs());

    RenderLoop.Run(Window, () => {
        if (!Paused) {
            OnUpdate(this, new EventArgs());
            Render();
        }
    });
}
protected override void Render() {
    // Clear Render Target. context.ClearRenderTargetView(...);
    // Set constant buffers.
    OnRender(this, new EventArgs());
    // Present back buffer.
}
```

Where `OnUpdate` will be utilized to update any objects on the screen, and `OnRender` will handle the new `Draw` calls.

---

### The Issue

The issue with this is that the old flow (within the render loop) cleared the render target, then rendered the camera, then began setting up the constant buffers. I've accomplished the first in that list rather easily, the second in the list is a simple `Draw` call with the new flow (and can come after setting up the buffers); but the issue is setting up the constant buffers. The following lines of code require the `Camera3D` object and I am having issues with moving this around.

```
ConstantBuffers.PerFrame perFrame = new ConstantBuffers.PerFrame();
perFrame.Light.Direction = (camera.TargetPosition - camera.Position);
perFrame.CameraPosition = camera.Position;
perFrame.CameraUp = camera.Up;
context.AddResource(perFrame);
```

This variable is then added to the resource list of the render target which must remain in `Engine3D` to prevent overly complicated drawing code.

There are other objects later in the code that rely on `Camera3D`'s `World` property, but once I solve how to separate the `Engine3D` from `Camera3D`, I'm sure I can take care of the rest easily.

---

### The Question

How can I separate this dependency from the `Engine3D` class?

A few things I have thought of are:

- Create a method that sets the buffers that must be called prior to draw.
- Make these properties static on `Camera3D` as there is always one camera, never more.
- Create a method specifically for the camera that handles this issue.
- Create a *middle man* class to handle all of this.
- Combine the `Engine3D` and `Camera3D` classes.

---

If there is any confusion as to what I am trying to achieve, please let me know and I will clarify the best I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The refactoring you want to do is called **[Pure Fabrication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)#Pure_fabrication)**.

---

A proposed solution of yours is to:

> Make these properties static on Camera3D as there is always one camera, never more.

---

I suggest that:

- Instead of making them static you can create another class (name it `StudioSetup`) that contains the fields which are needed in `Engine3D` (and you are looking to make static in your `Camera3D`);
- Populate an object of that class with current values and pass that to `Engine3D->Render()`;
- Now the dependency on `Camera3D` has been replaced with a dependency on `StudioSetup` object.

---

This is similar to your "Create a middleman class to handle all of this." solution. However, the middleman does not *do* anything except work as a one-way courier.